# Starting the first node in R3 Corda demobench in CentOS 7 causes core dump

Tags: corda

I'm running the latest public Corda demobench on linux(CentOS7) and when I attempt to start the first node, I get the following:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_cast'
>   what():  std::bad_cast

I was not getting this before I ran a "yum upgrade".

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,
Rob

Comment: Note that this does not occur on CentOS6 with the same Corda code base.

Comment: What's your Java version/provider?

Comment: Oracle jdk 1.8_161

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to Oracle jdk8u162 and the issue went away.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your distro has broken backwards compatibility. I suggest attaching gdb to the java process and waiting for the exception, then obtaining a backtrace to figure out where the issue is. DemoBench is written in Java/Kotlin so the fault lies outside that code.

Comment: Mike, are you asserting that the java version is incompatible with CentOS7?  Not sure I understand your point.  Please elaborate.  thanks.

Comment: I would hypothesize that the fault lies in a call to one of Corda's native libraries.